# Gremlin - best approach for querying Titan db from Node.js

Tags: node.js, graph-databases, gremlin, titan

I am using Titan graph db with Cassandra and Elasticsearch, Node.js and building RESTful web services.

I am confused whether to connect to Gremlin server using HTTP or Web Sockets.

Please share your learnings and let me know if there are any good reads or video tutorials on this.

Comment: Note that Titan is no longer developed; for new projects, you should consider [JanusGraph](http://janusgraph.org), which is a fork of Titan, actively developed and maintained by the community and already [in production use by a number of companies](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/#users). Existing Titan projects can be easily upgraded to use JanusGraph.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** Titan is no longer maintained, you should switch to [JanusGraph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/), which was forked from Titan and is maintained by an active community of users and developers.

You can use https://github.com/jbmusso/gremlin-javascript which can be found in the "Language drivers" section of the [Apache TinkerPop site](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/).

You can find sample code in https://github.com/jbmusso/gremlin-javascript/tree/master/gremlin-client